# Request to b2c login is blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, http, cors, fetch, azure-ad-b2c

I'm developing a web application, where the user is given a challenge from the web app that contains a URL to another website, where he's asked to sign-up.

The sign-up page is made using the sign-up flow in Azure AD B2C.

The response sent from my ASP.NET Core API looks like this:

```
var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(SignupController.Return), "Signup");
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl };
        properties.Items[AzureAdB2COptions.PolicyAuthenticationProperty] = AzureAdB2COptions.SignUpPolicyId;
        return Challenge(properties, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

The challenge is requested using Fetch API in Javascript, which looks like this:

```
            fetch(`/api/invitations/${invitationId}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            mode: 'cors'
        }).then(response => {
            // HTTP 301 response
            if (response.redirected) {
                console.log(response.url);
                window.location.href(response.url);
            }
        })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

However I keep getting this error:

[image: Error message]

As far as I understand this is a server problem, but I suppose its on b2clogin? I can't really see how I'm supposed to update the CORS policy. I can easily access the fetch URL as shown above by clicking on it, but the javascript code itself cannot redirect to it. I'm sure it's just a simple fix. I hope someone will help.

Comment: _“I can't really see how I'm supposed to update the CORS policy.”_ - _you_ are not supposed to do that in the first place, the remote party is. (Unless you are representing both here, that isn’t currently clear from your question.) The server you are making the request _to_, must allow for client-side scripted requests to this resource. The _requester_ can not do this from their end. That is kinda the point of CORS.

Comment: So there are no workaround, unless Azure AD B2C decides to allow client-side scripted requests?

Comment: The workaround would be the use a server-side proxy - your client-side JS request goes to your proxy, and your proxy then makes the request to that remote endpoint. Whether that will actually work, depends on whether that endpoint relies on any cookies send from the client, maybe checks the IP address against something, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here because of limited context. But, to fix this error, run below Azure CLI command in your Local:

```
az webapp cors add --resource-group myResourceGroup --name api-name --allowed-origins 'http://localhost:44315'
```

*Check out more about CORS policies in App service [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api#add-cors-functionality).*